# Line numbering in algorithmic

Tags: beamer, algorithms, line-numbering, algorithmicx

I want to change the first number of the line numbering in my algorithm, but how is it done?
This is my example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithmic, algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t, fragile]
    \frametitle{...}
       \begin{algorithm}[H]
       \caption{...}
       \begin{algorithmic}[1]
          \STATE ...
       \end{algorithmic}
       \end{algorithm}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

The first state should be numbered with 2 for example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The line number in `algorithmic` (from the [`algorithms` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms)) is governed by the counter `ALC@line`. The following MWE defines `\setalglineno{<num>}` which allows you to modify the number of any line in your `algorithmic`:

[image: Screenshot of Algorithm starting at line 2]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm,float}

\renewcommand\thealgorithm{}
\newcommand{\setalglineno}[1]{%
  \setcounter{ALC@line}{\numexpr#1-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t, fragile]
  \frametitle{...}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{...}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \setalglineno{2}% Set following line number to 2
      \STATE ...
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In fact, `\setalglineno{<num>}` sets `ALC@line` to `<num>-1`, since the algorithm is set in a list, where each line counter is incremented *before* it is set. So, technically, to obtain a line numbered 2, you need to set the counter value to 1.

A similar setup would be used within the `algpseudocode` (or equivalent) environments offered by [`algorithmicx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). For these you have to use `ALG@line` instead of `ALC@line` though.

Comment: Is it ``ALG@line`` instead of ``ALC@line``?

Comment: @hengxin: It's `ALC@line`. Try the other one and you'll see why.

Comment: ``ALG@line`` (not ``ALC@line``) works for me. Maybe it is because that I use ``algpseudocode + algorithmicx + algorithm`` environments.

Comment: @hengxin: Yes, there's a difference.

Comment: Hi, thanks for an answer. I have a follow up question. What changes should be done to your code, to enable me to pass `\ref{}` as a parameter to `\setalglineno`? I want to make a `\label` at the last line of the first algorithm and the second one would continue its numbering from there.

Comment: @jutky: For using references in counters you should typically include the [`refcount` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount). Then, whenever you have `\label{mylabel}`, you can use `\getrefnumber{mylabel}` to retrieve the appropriate label number for use.

Comment: @Werner Wow, thanks a lot. That is exactly what I need.

Comment: For algorithmicx, I had to use `ALG@line`. I did not have to use [`\makeatletter` or `\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/12478) though.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Sure. Also, there is no need for `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` here, as you mention, because you're not using `@` inside a control sequence.

Comment: @Werner Could it also be removed for the algorithmic example? Or is there a case where this is necessary?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: It is only necessary when you're dealing with control sequences that require the use of `@`. Counters with `@` in them are handled in a different way internally through something like `\setcounter{ALC@line}{...}` and therefore don't need `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`.

Comment: By the way, this works outside of the `beamer` context too. Just for reference, it's a generic solution.

Answer (score 2):

When an an algorithm is spread over multiple sections, inventing a new name for every label (as required by Werner's solution) can be cumbersome.

Building on the fact that line numbers are just counters, here is another approach: create a new counter for the line number. When an algorithmic environment is closed, save the counter. When resuming an algorithm, restore the counter.

MWE:

[image: Screenshot of line number continuations]

Corresponding code (the `ALG@line@` prefix was arbitrarily chosen):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\alglinenoNew}[1]{\newcounter{ALG@line@#1}}
\newcommand{\alglinenoPop}[1]{\setcounter{ALG@line}{\value{ALG@line@#1}}}
\newcommand{\alglinenoPush}[1]{\setcounter{ALG@line@#1}{\value{ALG@line}}}

\begin{document}

Start:
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State First
    \alglinenoNew{alg1}
    \alglinenoPush{alg1}
\end{algorithmic}

Continuation:
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \alglinenoPop{alg1}
    \State Second
    \State Third
    \alglinenoPush{alg1}
\end{algorithmic}

More:
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \alglinenoPop{alg1}
    \State Fourth
    \alglinenoPush{alg1}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```